# Axios post request error breaks javascript loop

Tags: node.js, axios

So, I've been struggling with how axios request breaking the flow in the project I'm working on.

It's an API, so it's using javascript with nodejs. This API allows to add users to a third party authentication API, if the user is added, then our API adds the user to the project DB and a few more actions such as permissions to different sections.

We have develop a feature to bulk add users using a xlsx template and reply with the amount of users added and the amount of errors.

When sending the request to the third party API we use Axios with a POST, but no matter if we use the catch option breaks the entire loop and returns the error for that single user that error-ed (with status code 400)

so basically what we have is something like this.

```
while (user < usersData.length) {
    //...
    // Validate a few permissions
    //...
    const person: any = {
        firstName: usersData[user].user_firstname,
        lastName: usersData[user].user_lastname,
        email: usersData[user].user_email,
        login: usersData[user].user_email,
        mobilePhone: usersData[user].user_phoneNbr,
    };

    await axios.post(`API_ADD_USER`, {profile: person}, {
        headers: { Authorization: `...` }
    }).then(function (data:any){
    
        // Add user to DB 
        // Grants permissions
        // Do some other Stuff
        // Does some logging
    
    })
    .catch(function (error:any) {
        usersError.push({
            user: currentEmail,
            message: `Cannot add user ${currentEmail};  API replied with error: ${error.message}`
        });
    });
}
```

the user receives the error in the UI and looking at the logs in the server, I see the same error:

`error=Error: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400 stack=Error: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400`

but the code stops there and the while loop does not continue, so I end up with no sign of the amount of users added nor the successful ones.

I tried to get rid of the catch, but Axios receives the error anyway and also breaks with the flow.

I've been trying to use google but no luck so far, don't know exactly why breaks the entire flow. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I think there's too much relevant code missing here.  Nothing you show here would terminate the loop unless your `const person` declaration throws.  An Axios rejection will just go to your `.catch()` which will handle the rejected promise and the loop will continue.  I think the issue is elsewhere in code you are not showing here.

Comment: You don't need to "await" axios promise if you use `then`. You have to choose between await or then to retrieve the promise response but not both. Using `then` here could cause your loop behave weirdly but I can't say with only the code that is here...